# error APPX1101: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'NLog.config'

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal, nlog

The project worked fine. However, once I uprated:

- Windows to latest current version 1709 OS Build 16299.125
- Visual Studio to 2017 version 15.6.6
- Target version to Windows Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)

I got fallowing error and:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwt5t.png)

Project's nuget packages:

- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.0.8
- NLog v4.5.3
- NLog.Config v4.5.3
- NLog.Schema v4.5.3

Project's Platform target is x86.

Properties of NLog.config file according https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting
are:

- Build Action - Content
- Copy to Output Directory - Copy if newer

I tried:

- clean / rebuild
- restart  visual Studio
- delete the bin and obj folders from the test project
- clear local nuget cache
- delete my local repo and make a new git clone
- upgrate the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
  package to current latest version 6.0.8
- change platform to (x86) or ARM

---

### Update

I manage got it working. I removed NLog.config file from

C:\Users\Aaaa\.nuget\packages\NLog.Config\4.5.3\contentFiles\any\any

and paste there mine version of NLog.config file from

C:\GIT\Zzzz\Test.Logging.Uwp

But It is not clean ideal solution, because it should not reuired copy/paste files around.
**Has anybody come up with better idea?**

Comment: I aslo upgrated NLog nuget packages to latest version 4.5.3 but still I doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the same problem. If you have already created  `NLog.config` file manually in the root of your `UWP` project, then there is no need in the optional `NLog.config` package.
Uninstall the `NLog.config` through `Nuget Package Manager`.